# Adding metadata that describes each attribute field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, geopackage, metadata

Using a GeoPackage layer at 3.28.9, I would like to add descriptive information for each of the layer's attribute fields as metadata.  However, there is no Layer Properties > Metadata tab for attribute information (please see screenshot below).

I've searched here at SEGIS as well as the internet at large with no success.

How do I add metadata that describes each attribute field?

[image]

As a comparison, ArcCatalog does a nice job of displaying a layer's metadata - *including attribute information* - using FGDC standards, [see the guide here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/metadata/illustrated-guide-to-complete-fgdc-metadata.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_01B7AC211E2040F9A436CA03D6A0E094).

The image below is taken from that guide, and it shows how attributes (called *fields*) have their own separate section within the overall metadata.

I'm looking for an analogous solution in QGIS.

[image]

Comment: There are some areas where QGIS is more advanced than other GIS software. Metadata is not one of them.

Comment: Why not use the abstract?

Comment: Well sure, you *could* use the abstract pane (taken to the extreme, *all* metadata could be shoehorned into a single Abstract section!).  For many of us, the ability to organize and describe a table's attributes and their respective code values is a primary reason to have metadata in the first place, and that was the impetus for my OP.

Comment: To extreme I agree that you could do that, but it wasn't what I was suggesting.  My questioning was more on where (which metadata element) you would expect to see them.  I can't think of a standard that maps individual attribute value descriptions, and with that thinking the best location seems to be abstract.  If there was some other description, say an XML schema, you could use some type of resource link.

Comment: Maybe on the fields tab, or in a new fields tab within the metadata tab.

Comment: Please see my OP edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to add a human readable description as a field comment with the QGIS Browser.

[image]

Once the comment is added it is visible in the Browser

[image]

and similarly from the Table of Contents - Layer properties

[image]

QGIS is placing this metadata into "gpkg_data_columns" table that is defined in the GeoPackage standard and is therefore available for other GeoPackage clients which implement that part of the standard.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your solution appears to be the best way for QGIS to handle attribute metadata at this time.  Although this feature is a big improvement for QGIS, it is still short of a complete, detailed metadata format.  Note that this feature is not available at 3.28, but it does work at 3.32.

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at the Metadata extension for GeoPackage? This appears to at least enable field-level metadata, though I have not used it.

See here: http://www.geopackage.org/guidance/extensions/metadata.html.

And here: [Storing metadata in Geopackage for QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298523/storing-metadata-in-geopackage-for-qgis)

As a much cruder and alternate approach, I tried filling out the "Comment" field when creating new fields in a GeoPackage layer via the QGIS 3.28.4 interface--but none of my comments persisted. This appears to be a bug ([How to add a comment to a source field in QGIS 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286920/how-to-add-a-comment-to-a-source-field-in-qgis-3)) but perhaps it's worth testing on later QGIS versions.

Comment: I looked at your link and quickly realized that it was beyond my simple-minded ability!  Regarding adding comments that persist, that capability is now available at 3.32.